# Setting a size limit for current syslog

Tags: rsyslog, logrotate

Based on other threads, the only way to set a size limit on current `syslog` (`/var/log/syslog`) seems to be via `rsyslog` which is a bit tricky. I ended up replacing the line below in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`:

```
.*;auth,authpriv.none       -/var/log/syslog
```

with these 2 lines:

```
$outchannel mysyslog,/var/log/syslog,1073741824,/home/username/.me/log_rotation_script
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          :omfile:$mysyslog
```

My issue is that regardless of what I put in the `log_rotation_script`, I get the same error when I clear `syslog` and restart `rsyslog.service`. After `syslog` reaches 1G, `rsyslog` always produces the same error below:

```
Mar 01 22:17:27 # rsyslogd[341844]: program '/home/username/.me/log_rotation_script' (pid 341977) exited with status 1 [v8.2001.0]

Mar 01 22:17:27 # rsyslogd[341844]: file size limit cmd for file '/var/log/syslog' did no resolve situation  [v8.2001.0]
```

It's returning `status 1` even if I put only an `echo` command inside the `log_rotation_script`!

Note that there's nothing wrong with the script or the path, as executing the contents of the file in the path above works without any problem if I execute e.g. with the command below:

```
bash /home/username/.me/log_rotation_script
```

What am I missing here? Please help!

Comment: How is `syslog` hitting 1G so quickly that you need to write a rotation script for it? It usually doesn't grow at velocity 

Comment: A bug in dash to dock plug-in in gnome

Answer (score 0):

Rsyslog starts running as **root** but then drops privileges and runs as **syslog** user. Check configuration directives `$PrivDropToUser` and `$PrivDropToGroup` in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
$PrivDropToUser syslog
$PrivDropToGroup syslog
```

Since **syslog** user does not have much permissions, it cannot run `logrotate` because `logrotate` needs access to its state file which does not allow access for **syslog** user. Also in my case I had to restart rsyslog after log rotation, but again, **syslog** user didn't have permissions to do that.

I was trying other ways how to overcome these limitations (sudoers, additional permissions), but each time I resolved one issue, I got another one, so I considered `logrotate` and `$outchannel` feature useless.

Seems it returns error for any command that you put in `$outchannel`, except `rm` and `mv` (those two commands are working). I was trying to `truncate` file, but it fails with `program '/usr/bin/truncate' (pid 1234) exited with status 1 [v8.2001.0]`, however `rm` is working and you don't even need to reload rsyslog:

```
$outchannel syslog_file,/var/log/syslog,100000,/usr/bin/rm /var/log/syslog

*.*;auth,authpriv.none         :omfile:$syslog_file
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to truncate the logs by specifying the size to the truncate command i.e `$outchannel mysyslog,/var/log/syslog,1048576,/usr/bin/truncate -s 1M /var/log/syslog`. Otherwise `rm` works just fine as mentioned in [Oleksandr's](https://askubuntu.com/a/1426991/1686899) solution.

Comment: rm or remove does not set a size it deletes the current file. Not what was asked.